# Mysterious whitespace between "inline-block" divs

Tags: html, css

I have a layout like this: [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/itimeheke/bysMR/)

Between .td's is some white-space, even if margin and padding is set to 0.

Why is this happening and how to fix this? Negative margin-left maybe? Or any better solutions?

```
<style>
.tr {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-spacing: 0;
}
.td {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
<div class="tr" style="width: 150px;">
    <div class="td" style="width: 50px; background-color: #CCC;"></div>
    <div class="td" style="width: 50px; background-color: #AAA;"></div>
    <div class="td" style="width: 50px; background-color: #666;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Add comments:

```
<div class="tr" style="width: 150px;">
    <div class="td" style="width: 50px; background-color: #CCC;"></div><!--
    --><div class="td" style="width: 50px; background-color: #AAA;"></div><!--
    --><div class="td" style="width: 50px; background-color: #666;"></div>
</div>
```

You can write everything on the same line, too, but it looks cleaner with comments.

---

**Solution 2:** Add `font-size:0` to the parent element. Don't forget to define the font-size for child elements:

```css
.tr {
  font-size: 0;
}
.td {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: nice one, solution 2 quite easy to implement, 1 up!

Comment: When using HAML, I can avoid whitespace from being rendered inside and outside the tag with `%div<>`

Answer (score 2):

use float

```
.td {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
```

Comment: I was using float, but it pushed third box to new line when width: 60px was applied.

Comment: yes because the width of parent is less then the combine width of children so either you can increase width of parent or you can comment the extra space in the inline divs  
example: http://jsfiddle.net/bysMR/7/

Answer (score 0):

The sapces/linebreakes between your inline-block elementes are displayed by the browser. You can [remove them](http://jsfiddle.net/bysMR/4/), but possible better use some sort of floating on your td class.

I am not sure what kind of data you are trying to display with your markup, but for tabular data the use of tables is perfectly finde! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Inline-blocks are treated as inline elements so empty spaces separate them as usual words in parent element.

I propose 2 solutions:

1. You can fix it by removing spaces between `inline-block` divs, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/f3AKu/
2. You can set font-size of container to 0 so spaces won't be noticeable. This way you won't modify HTML markup, only CSS rules. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wC68h/

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this issue you have to hav your divs in one line:

```
<div class="td" style="width: 50px; background-color: #CCC;"></div><div class="td" style="width: 50px; background-color: #AAA;"></div><div class="td" style="width: 50px; background-color: #666;"></div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way to accomplish zero space between inline-blocks was in CSS, with the parent having `font-size:0` and child having `font-size:16px`. That said, there are a few other ways to do it with HTML and CSS. Here's a live pen:

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/hmlqF