# Why justified CSS grid menu must have a space between li elements

Tags: html, css

I know that this must be one of most asked questions, but I really want to understand - **why** justified grid menu must have a space between `<li>` elemtents?

I made an example here: http://jsbin.com/oNibesA/1/edit

CSS:

```
.inline-list {
    text-align: justify;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.inline-list:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.inline-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.inline-list li:before {
    content: ' ';
}

.inline-list li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

This HTML (with spaces) works fine - it spreads the elements evenly in one line:

```
<ul class="inline-list">
    <li><a>Everything</a></li>
    <li><a>Is</a></li>
    <li><a>Fine</a></li>
    <li><a>With</a></li>
    <li><a>Multiline</a></li>
    <li><a>HTML</a></li>
</ul>
```

But this HTML (all in one line without spaces) doesn't spread evenly:

```
<ul class="inline-list"><li><a>This</a></li><li><a>Is</a></li><li><a>A</a></li><li><a>Weird</a></li><li><a>CSS/HTML</a></li><li><a>Bug</a></li></ul>
```

Now I know that it happens, but I'm curious - **why** it happens?
And can you somehow fix this (for example, put the space between the `<li>` elements) just by using CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysterious whitespace between "inline-block" divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982197/mysterious-whitespace-between-inline-block-divs)

Comment: there's no space(white-space) in between li, it behaves like a word where li are inline-boxes/letters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items)

Comment: you coud use display:flex; justify-content:space-between; instead if you minify your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would `display:flex;` be an alternative if you minify your HTML ? 
http://jsbin.com/oMIdODaZ/1/

```
.inline-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
}


li {
  display:inline-block;
  background:gray;
}
```

limits at this avearge time:  http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: You seemed to have missed all of the prefixed properties you'll need to actually make this work.  So no, this actually ends up being *more* code than what the OP has.

Comment: at this time prefix are usefull and can be easely added via javascript. caniuse.com mentions webkit and moz, wich for moz is actually not needed in  FF 26 :)

Comment: Also, this question technically does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: i did in comments below the question, and it does give an alternative in case of minified HTML

Answer (score 3):

*why justified grid menu must have a space between `<li>` elemtents?*

That's because with that space each `inline-block` is considered like one separated element, lets say in case of justify that space is rendered and works to set each element like a single word. Then justify can do his job.

If you remove the space is like you are getting together all blocks like one word and justify can just break it.

**Edit**

As You can see on this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NHxXU/1/)** if you save that whitespace `inline-block` can work as single words other properties like `letter-spacing` and `word-spacing` also modify the inline-block behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no whitespace between the different words they are considered as one single word. `justify` doesn't have any effect on one word, since it changes the space between words.