# CSS Positioning: Creating exact overlap with negative margin is off by several pixels

Tags: css

I have 2 divs I want to exactly overlap horizontally using negative margin-left.

HTML:

```
<div id=one></div>
<div id=two></div>
```

CSS:

```
body{margin:0px;padding:0px,border:0px}

#one  {width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;}
#two  {width:100px;height: 50px;background-color:blue;}

#one,#two{display:inline-block;}

#two{margin-left:-100px;}
```

Before negative margin each div is 100px wide:

[image]

After negative margin the divs are 4px from overlapping exactly:

[image]

Why does setting a negative margin on the second div not cause it to exactly overlap the first div?

BTW, I'm just experimenting with margin-left...I know I can absolutely position the 2 divs inside a relative wrapper.

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982197/mysterious-whitespace-between-inline-block-divs

Comment: @Paulie_D  I now understand that your dup-question-reference tells me that inline-block is causing the alignment difference.  I'll leave this question here because future SO visitors might want to know that negative-margins must be adjusted for the inline-block spacing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline block has weird "bug" you could call it, that applies a 4px space between elements assuming a default font-size.  This is created from the line-break between your div's.  You'll find that you can fix this quite simply by making your negative higher.

`margin-left: -104px`;

This will fix your issue, but it's also not the only way to fix it.

---

You could do this... Instead of:

```
<div id=one></div>
<div id=two></div>
```

Delete the line-break between the div's so they are this:

```
<div id=one></div><div id=two></div>
```

This will also fix the issue.

---

You could alternatively set the font-size of their containing element to 0.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div id=one></div>
<div id=two></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container { font-size: 0; }
```

But wait!  There is more.  You could comment out the line-break.

```
<div id=one></div><!--
--><div id=two></div>
```

---

You could drop the ending > to the beginning of the next element.

```
 <div id=one></div
><div id=two></div>
```

Comment: I believe there was another way using word-space: nowrap or something like that.

Comment: I see...inline-block makes the html element markup "space sensitive".  Thanks!  I see how all your solutions work except the font-size solution--why does that work?

Comment: @JustAsking - The 4px space is a product of the line-break, sort of like a space.  That size is governed by the size of your font.  Obviously the space between letters is dependent on font-size, this is the same way.  Setting the font-size to 0 sets everything related to the font, to 0.  Consequently that weird 4px space becomes 0 also, and thus, fixes the issue. ;)

Comment: Understood...font-size:0 makes any offending spacing zero-width.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements are sensitive to their structure in your HTML. Since both divs are separated by a line break, they have a small "margin" between them like letters in a sentence would (which is pretty much the point of inline elements).

```
<div id=one></div> <!-- Here -->
<div id=two></div>
```

Change the structure of your HTML to remove this space:

```
<div id=one></div><div id=two></div>
```

Or you can use comments to negate the line break:

```
<div id=one></div><!--
--><div id=two></div>
```

Comment: I see...inline-block makes the html element markup "space sensitive". Thanks!